# MOXy exception with XmlAdapter and JSON

Tags: java, json, moxy

I'm running MOXy 2.5.0 and getting a `ClassCastException` with an `XmlAdapter`, but only when trying to output JSON; the XML output works fine.

I've got a wrapper class that looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public abstract class ListWrapper<T> implements List<T>
{
    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    @XmlElement
    private Foo foo;  // stuff specific to my problem domain

    public ListWrapper()
    {
    }

    public ListWrapper(Foo foo, List list)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.list = list;
    }

    // ... implementation of List<T> using the list member ...
}
```

There are descendants of this class that look like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "recordList")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class RecordList extends ListWrapper<Record>
{
    public RecordList()
    {
        super();
    }

    public RecordList(Foo foo, List<Record> list)
    {
        super(foo, list);
    }

    @Override
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "records")
    @XmlElement(name = "record", type = Record.class)
    public List<Record> getList()
    {
        return super.getList();
    }
}
```

There is then an XmlAdapter for `RecordList` that looks like this:

```
public class RecordListAdapter extends XmlAdapter<RecordList, RecordList>
{
    @Override
    public RecordList unmarshal(RecordList v) throws Exception
    {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public RecordList marshal(RecordList v) throws Exception
    {
        return v;
    }
}
```

Finally there is a class that contains members like `RecordList` and declares them as such:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "container")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Container
{
    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(RecordListAdapter.class)
    protected RecordList recordList;

    // ... other stuff ...
}
```

With the reference JAXB implementation this works fine in both XML and JSON (we were using Jackson for the JSON logic).  With a change to MOXy (and removal of Jackson) I'll get an exception trace similar to the following when asking for JSON output.

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException - with linked exception:[Exception [EclipseLink-25003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred marshalling the object
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-3001] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [1], of class [class com.example.Record], could not be converted to [class com.example.RecordList].
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Record cannot be cast to com.example.RecordList]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:403)
...
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred marshalling the object
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-3001] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [1], of class [class com.example.Record], could not be converted to [class com.example.RecordList].
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Record cannot be cast to com.example.RecordList
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.marshalException(XMLMarshalException.java:97)
...
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-3001] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [1], of class [class com.example.Record], could not be converted to [class com.example.RecordList].
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Record cannot be cast to com.example.RecordList
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException.couldNotBeConverted(ConversionException.java:87)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Record cannot be cast to com.example.RecordList
    at com.example.RecordListAdapter.marshal(RecordListAdapter.java:5)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.XMLJavaTypeConverter.convertObjectValueToDataValue(XMLJavaTypeConverter.java:172)
```

I'm not sure why MOXy is trying to tread a `Record` as a `RecordList`, but it appears as though that's what is happening.  Like I said, this does not happen with the reference (i.e. Sun) implementation of JAXB; it only happens when I'm trying to use MOXy.

Any ideas here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After you removed Jackson you no longer have a write adapter for JSON. You need to tell the server how it should produce JSON.

Comment: The system produces JSON just fine for other calls; MOXy has it built in.

Comment: Fair enough. The stack trace you linked seems to indicate that Moxy isn't trying to generate JSON at all, right?

Comment: That is what it indicates, yes.  But you can see that it is MOXy handling the `XmlAdapter`.  That's what the `XMLJavaTypeConverter` class is.  Like I noted, JSON works fine for other calls and I don't have a `MessageBodyWriter` defined.  Creating one for JSON does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

One difference between MOXy and the other technologies that you are using is that MOXy will treat `RecordList` and `ListWrapper` as a `java.util.List` as it implements `java.util.List`.  As such a `XmlAdapter` can not be applied to it, as it can only apply to items in the collection.

Comment: So with MOXy we would have to use just aggregation with the underlying list instead?  The only reason we have the `XmlAdapter` is because of Sun's behavior; it will automatically marshal the `List` in its own way, and using the adapter got around that behavior.  MOXy seems to do the same when marshalling to XML (i.e. ignores the adapter), but balks when marshalling to JSON.